# turtle python on mac

Tags: python, macos, turtle-graphics

I'm learning Python on a Mac and I am initiating the program through Terminal. I'm trying to save all of the code through my text editor Sublime but unfortunately I'm having issues importing Turtle.

I start by putting:

```
import Turtle
turtle.showturtle()
```

in Sublime but I get an error:

```
Gabriels-Air:Desktop gabrielmendez$ python intro.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "intro.py", line 38, in <module>
import Turtle
ImportError: No module named Turtle
```

My file is named intro.py and I did change the directory to my desktop since that's where my file is at.  I've used Turtle straight on the terminal but I want to be able to keep the code.  I've looked online and I can't find my answer. Any help please?

Comment: `import turtle`, not `import Turtle`

Comment: also, `tutle.showturtle()` shouldn't be on the same line as `import turtle`

Comment: Thank you Brandon!

Comment: Sorry WhiskeyAndRye that mistake was made during the import info. My bad

Answer (score 2):

Python is case-sensitive.

Python reads

```
import Turtle
```

as you trying to import functions from Turtle.py. However, the module in python is lowercase, so use this line:

```
import turtle
```